Compactness in the weak topology
Problem :
Let $E$ be a Banach space and $F\subset E$ be such that for every $\epsilon>0\ \exists \text{ a weakly compact }F_\epsilon\subset E$ with the property $F\subset F_\epsilon+\epsilon B_E$. Here $B_E$ is the norm closed unit ball in $E$. I'm supposed to show $G=\overline{F}^{\sigma(E,E^*)}$ is weakly compact.
Solution :
Let $\epsilon>0$ be fixed. It's easy to see $G\subset F_\epsilon+\epsilon B_E$ since it's a sum of a compact and a closed set in the weak topology. Moreover considering the canonical linear isometry $J:E\rightarrow E^{**}$ one can easily show that $J:(E, \sigma(E,E^*) )\rightarrow(J(E), \sigma(E^{**},E^*) )$ is a continuous bijection wrt their corresponding topologies. Then $J(G)\subset J(F_\epsilon)+\epsilon B_{E^{**}}$ is weakstar closed and hence weakstar compact as the right-hand set is a sum of two compact sets(Banach-Alaoglu). Therefore $G=J^{-1}J(G)$ is weakly compact in $E$.
Question : if the above proof is alright, then where exactly did we require every $\epsilon>0$ ? I feel only a single positive $\epsilon$ should work.
I have seen someone arguing in the following manner that $J(G)\subset J(F_\epsilon)+\epsilon B_{E^{**}}\subset J(E)+\epsilon B_{E^{**}}\implies J(G)\subset \cap_{\epsilon>0} J(E)+\epsilon B_{E^{**}}=J(E) $ but isn't it obvious that $J(G)\subset J(E)$ in the first place?
$\bf\text{update :}$ $J(G)$ is not weakstar closed in $E^{**} $ a priori as pointed out by Evan below. But we show that eventually. Notice $\overline{J(G)}^{\sigma(E^{**},E^*)}\subset J(F_\epsilon)+\epsilon B_{E^{**}}\subset J(E)+\epsilon B_{E^{**}} $ for all $\epsilon>0$, implies $\overline{J(G)}^{\sigma(E^{**},E^*)}\subset \cap_{\epsilon>0} J(E)+\epsilon B_{E^{**}}=J(E)\implies J(G)= \overline{J(G)}^{\sigma(E^{**},E^*)} $ and the argument goes through.

Why $\overline {J(G)} \subset J(E)$ implies that $J(G)= \overline{J(G)}$ in weak-star topology?

It's the smallest closed set containing $J(G)$ and $J(G)$ is already closed in $J(E)$ wrt. subspace topology.

I think it looks good now

The problem is that $J(G)$ is not weak-star closed in $E^{**},$ only in $J(E)$, whereas $J(F_\epsilon) +\epsilon B_{E^{**}}$ is weak-star compact in $E^{**}$ and not $J(E)$. So you can not infer that $J(G)$ is weak-star compact. As a counter example you can take $F=B_E, \epsilon=1, F_\epsilon = \{0\}$ in any nonreflexive space. Your argument would work for $E$  reflexive.
I think you should consider sequential compactness plus a diagonal argument, although I have not fully looked into it.

$J(F_\epsilon)$ is weakstar compact in $E^{**}$.

You changed your whole answer.

Indeed, I did. Do you agree now?

$J(G)$ is not weakstar closed in $E^{}$ is correct. But $J(F_\epsilon)+\epsilon B_{E^{}}$ is not even a subset of $J(E)$. So you can't talk about its compactness there. I got your point. May be that's why we need $\forall \epsilon>0$. This result holds in nonreflexive Banach spaces.
